# Prevent a user from changing his own password in OWA

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-account, outlook-web-access

We are using a shared M365 account for an application.

The account is shared between 10-15 people.

Sometimes someone feels funny and is logging in to Outlook and changes the password.

I want to stop people from going [here](https://myaccount.microsoft.com/?ref=MeControl) and changing the account's password and the the other people who use the account cannot login.

Anyone who can help, please?

Comment: In the properties of the user, on the active directory, enable `User cannot change password`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing and research, we can disable users from resetting their own passwords, but not password changes.

In addition, there is a similar thread here that discusses this issue:[Remove Change password on OWA office 365 - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482741/remove-change-password-on-owa-office-365)

Experts likewise show that you can't stop users from changing their passwords in various ways. It does not prevent users from being redirected to:
https://myaccount.microsoft.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @OneNotes 
Just checking in to follow up with this thread. If you have any questions or need further help on this issue, please feel free to post back.